# Nested Lists on same Page in MeteorJS

Tags: meteor

I have three lists on the same page which I want to fill with list-items. The list items are associated to the lists by a field called listId

My publications:

```
Meteor.publish('lists', function(options) {
  return Lists.find({}, options);
});
Meteor.publish('listItems', function(listId) {
  return Cards.find({listId: listId});
});
```

My lists-page.js (this._id param is passed with iron-router.):

```
Template.listsPage.helpers({
    lists: function(){
        return Lists.find({listsPageId: this._id});
    },
    listItems: function(listId){
        //??
        return ListItems.find({listId: listId})
    }
});
```

My lists-page.html:

```
<template name="listsPage">
    {{#each lists}}
        <ul>
            <li>{{title}}</li>
            {{#each listItems}}
                 <li>{{listItemTitle}}</li>
            {/each}
    {{#each lists}}
</template>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general recommendation, I would avoid collections and publish functions which have generic names like "lists" and "items". I find it makes code incredibly hard to understand. That being said, I think the confusion here is about the name associated with a publish function and the name of the underlying collection.

The name of the publish function (`listItems` in this case) is used only to facilitate the activation by a subscription, and has no other meaning. The function publishes a set of documents in the `Cards` collection to the client. Those documents should subsequently be retrieved from the client's local database using the `Cards` collection.

So I think the code you are looking for is:

```
listItems: function() {
  return Cards.find({listId: this._id});
}
```

The context in which the `listItems` helper is run is that of a `List` document. So the id for `listId` should be `this._id`. Let me know if that doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Thanks David. I agree with you on the generic-name-issue. I'm thinking on reimplementing the whole list/list-item thing differently. Your answer brought me on the right track. Much appreciated.